# Django doesn't validate on create?

Tags: django, validation

Is it the case that the `create` function doesn't validate according to the model specifications? Here's my model:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

And I use this function in my `view`:

```
new_contact = Contact.objects.create(firstname=a,
    lastname=b,
    email=c)
# where a, b, & c are empty strings in request.POST, which shouldn't validate
```

The call to `create` goes through without a problem. But, that shouldn't be the case. The model specifies those fields as required. In fact, if I go to the admin panel and view this object, I can't save it (without making any changes) because it yells at me that the fields are required.

**Is it normal behavior for `create` to not validate?**

**How can I force it to validate?**

Comment: @e4c5 Yes, I created a form, but that didn't solve my problem. At this point I'm just accepting several forms in one view. It forces the user to do a page refresh just to add auxiliary information to the main model being created, which I don't like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up forms and models.

[Field.blank](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.blank)

> If True, the field is allowed to be blank. Default is False.
>
> Note that this is different than null. null is purely
>   database-related, whereas blank is validation-related. If a field has
>   blank=True, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a
>   field has blank=False, the field will be required.

So yes, it's normal behaviour for the model to not bother with validation of blanks.

If you want to make sure that user input of blanks doesn't end up in the database you should use a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) for that. It's most un-django like to directly use request.POST

Comment: Correct. It is my situation that this object being created is asynchronous from the main form being submitted, and is only conditionally required. I do not have a form defined for this model.

Comment: well guess you are going to have to create one now or use a modelfactory

Answer (score 4):

From Django's [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean), it says that you need to explicitly call model validation related methods i.e., `full_clean, clean`, for model validation to take effect.

You can follow the examples available in Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/) to implement your own validation sequence in your model.

Comment: The link is no longer valid

Answer (score 1):

1. setting `blank=False` is a validation requirement and not a DB constraint.
2. calling `create`, `save` etc. do not check validations for you.

You need to enforce the validations yourself by calling `contact.full_clean()`

From the documentation:

> Note that full_clean() will not be called automatically when you call your model’s save() method. You’ll need to call it manually when you want to run one-step model validation for your own manually created models.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Answer (score 1):

Django validation is mostly application level validation and not validation at DB level. Also Model validation is not run automatically on save/create of the model. If you want to validate your values at certain time in your code then you need to do it manually.

For example:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
form app.models import MyModel

instance = MyModel(name="Some Name", size=15)
try:
    instance.full_clean()
except ValidationError:
    # Do something when validation is not passing
else:
    # Validation is ok we will save the instance
    instance.save()
```